# problema con visualización de un campo

Tags: javascript

una consulta que espero me puedan ayudar a resolver..

por que este script javascript solo sirve si se visualiza en PC y no en móvil... ¿Qué ajuste le hago para que en el explorador del móvil la visualice igual y haga lo mismo que cuando la veo en el explorador del PC? pues en el movil el input se comporta como un simple input normal y necesito que el input separe el texto mientras se escribe así ejemplo: ABC-123

Gracias!!!

```html
<input name="placa" type="text" id="placa" onkeyup="form1.placa.value=form1.placa.value.toUpperCase()" size="8" maxlength="7" style="font-size:25px;">
<script>
document.getElementById("placa").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (this.value.length<3 && /[A-Za-z]/.test(e.key)) {
        this.value+=e.key.toUpperCase();
    }
    if (this.value.length>=4 && /[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(e.key)) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.value.length==3) {
        this.value+="-";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: no comprendo cual es tu problema, usas alguna libreria como Jquery o solo js puro.

Comment: Hola mil gracias por responder...pues es asi como lo vez, el problema es que al visualizar la web en explorador desde un PC funciona perfecto se visualiza perfecto, pero al verla desde un explorador de un smarthPhone se comporta como un input normal y necesito que se separe el texto mientras se escribe asi ABC-123... Ayudaaa

Comment: pero no estas gregando el codigo completo? porque sale que form1 no esta definido, es decir tiene ese inpu dentro de las etiqueta form?

Comment: De nuevo Gracias CRIS19N por responder... si claro que esta dentro de un form, solo que tome la parte que necesitaba mostrar

Comment: voy a probarlo de forma local, para ver que puede ser, y editare mi respuesta si encuentro el problema

Comment: Mil gracias CRIS19N espero me puedas ayudar a corregir o a cambiar para visualizar el campo funcional en explorador de movil de la misma manera que se ve en explorador de un pc...

Comment: estoy haciendo una prueba con el depurador de google para movil, quiza podrias buscar como deburar en el navegador chrome en android, y eso quiza te sea util, para econtrar el problema, yo lo estoy haciendo con jquery, porque no manejo muy bien js puro

Comment: amigo no entiendo porque no funciona para ti, lo prove en mi dispositivo y funciona igual. aunque sí hay algo que noto, cuando escribo con el teclado movil no pasa nada, solo convierte a mayuscula, pero cuando escribo con el depurador de google, funciona, no sé que relacion pueda haber ahi

Comment: ahora cambie de keypress a keyup y funciona en android pero no en pc, jajaja creo que tiene que ver con esa accion

Comment: Hola CRIS19N.. si es el mismo problema que presento.. y la verdad es algo que necesito que se vea en móvil tal cual que al ir escribiendo en el input lo haga así ABC-321 tampoco se que pasa!!!

Comment: encontre un problema, me gustaria que explicaras bien el problema, para ver si puedo recontruirlo con jquery, ya que con tu codigo encontre que esta leyendo cualquier tecla, por eso con keyup no funciona como se espera.

Comment: lo que yo entiendo es que esta comparando tecla por tecla, creo que se puede hacer eso mismo con el evento keyup, y no compararlo con la tecla que se escribe, sino con el valor del input, pero no sé si estoy en lo correcto

Answer (score 1):

Código completo con los FORM

```html
<form  id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="placa" type="text" id="placa" onkeyup="form1.placa.value=form1.placa.value.toUpperCase()" size="8" maxlength="7" style="font-size:25px;">
   
   </form>
<script>
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const value = document.getElementById("placa").value;

var expresion1 =/[A-Za-z]/;

var expresion2 = /[A-Za-z0-9]/;

input.onkeyup = logKey;

function logKey(e) {
 
    if (this.value.length<3 && value.match(expresion1)==true) {
        this.value+=value.value.toUpperCase();
    }

    if (this.value.length>=4 && value.match(expresion2)==true) {
        return;
    }
    if (this.value.length==3) {
        this.value+="-";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}


</script>
```

Comment: es lo más cercano posible, no manejo mucho js puro, pero puede que te sirva de alguna ayuda, mientras sigo probando.